# not to create new commit-id on gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I use two gerrit now. 
When I push the code, I used to this.

```
git add 
git commit -m "Update OOOO module, fix the bug A1-09000"
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master

-----modify sth.
 git add src/editedfile.c
 git commit --amend
 git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

The problem is, it works only for a gerrit A. The other gerrit B always create a new commit-id. So I couldn't push changes for a new patch set.

I tried to put this.

```
scp -p -P 29417 id@gerritUrl:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks
```

1. Problems on gerrit A
   Create patch set is ok. But always asking a gerrit password on push. Even I register ssh key.
2. Problems on gerrit B
   Can not create a patch set. but it does not ask password.

For me, more important proejct is on the gerrit B. So I need to push the new patch set. What is the problem of this?

Comment: Gerrit's SSH server doesn't allow passwords, so you're either not pushing via SSH to server A (perhaps HTTP, where passwords _are_ used) or you're pushing to the wrong port so you reach the system's SSH server rather than Gerrit's (which usually runs on port 29418).

Comment: Temporary war might be adding change id manually, by running "git commit --amend"

Answer (score 0):

After `git commit` check the commit message itself by `git log`. the [changeId](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/user-changeid.html#description) should be placed in the commit msg. I think the first commit did not contain changeId either. You can deny commits without changeId - it can be set in the project admin page. Also check the content of the downloaded hook in .git/hooks. commit-msg should have a header in the beginning. For the first problem, can you ssh into gerrit A without password? this behavior only happens at push?